# visually explication of dense layer of keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am learning keras and I would like to know how the dense layers of keras are visually interpreted, I do not understand very well the concepts and arguments of

```
model.add (Dense (512, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784,)))
```

I know that input_shape = (784,) would be drawn as 784 input neurons ,but I don't understand what 512 is?

Answer (score 1):

You can find more details about the arguments of Dense Layer in Keras Sequential model [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense).

Example

```
# as first layer in a sequential model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(16,)))
# now the model will take as input arrays of shape (*, 16)
# and output arrays of shape (*, 32)

# after the first layer, you don't need to specify
# the size of the input anymore:
model.add(Dense(32))
```

So basically 512 represents dimensionality of the output space of your model.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/), first argument is the "Units" ,output size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

512 is the number of neurons in the dense layer. Each neuron is connected to the input layer (which have the input_shape)

Answer (score 0):

model.add (Dense (512, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (784,)))??

here you use the sequence model of Keras, so you add layers sequence.
in your model by name 'model' you add a Dense layer with 512 neurons.
your activation is relu ( 0 <= output <=1 ) and you can use others like 'sigmoid'(0 <= output <=1 ) leacky relu ( -0.1 <= output <=1 )
softmax function
view below link

> [activation functions](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/)

last but not the least, input_shape = (784,)
the shape of your data is 784 neurons in the input layer

this layer makes 784 * 512 branches that multiply 784 into them and find 512 output: